# Same sub-query used multiple times in a single query

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I am running a query that contains **same** sub-query used multiple times in a `WHERE` clause.

I have a table having tow fields `client_id`, `buyer_id`.

The sub-query returns the list of dates to be excluded from the result.

This is how I am using it.

```
SELECT
  id, client_id, buyer_id
FROM relation
WHERE
  client_id NOT IN (SELECT <some_id> FROM <some_table> WHERE ...)
  AND buyer_id NOT IN (SELECT <some_ids> FROM <some_table> WHERE ...)
```

This is working as expected but what bothers me that there are two same sub-queries. I wonder if there is a way that I can use it once and use the result for both places.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try replacing that subquery with a JOIN?

Comment: @bluefeet, I have simplified this query a long way just to give you the real problem. Also I am unable to understand how `JOIN`'s `ON` clause would look like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write this using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT
    id, client_id, buyer_id
FROM relation AS r
WHERE NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT 1 
        FROM <some_table> 
        WHERE (r.client_id = <some_id> OR r.buyer_id = <some_id>) 
          AND ...
      ) ;
```

Comment: I am getting `Error correlating field` exception in a similar query.

Answer (score 1):

Queries of the form:

```
select ...
from <main query>
where <select field> not in (select <subquery field> from <subquery>)
```

can normally be reformulated as:

```
select <main query fields>
from <main query>
left join <subquery> on <select field> = <subquery field>
where <subquery field> is null
```

If the sub-query you are using is **exactly** the same for both client_id and buyer_id, it should therefore be possible to reformulate your query as:

```
SELECT id, client_id, buyer_id
FROM relation
LEFT JOIN <some_table> ON <some_id> IN (client_id, buyer_id)
WHERE <some_id> IS NULL
```

- thus effectively using the subquery only once in the query.

Comment: A solution with a join might not return the same result as a solution with a sub-query.

Comment: Exactly that what I am experiencing. It is not returning the same row, rather more rows. Also taking extra time as well. My original query is running in 41 seconds, and when I used it in JOIN it took 61 seconds.

Comment: @TalhaAhmedKhan Can you provide an [SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with some data? I do think that this query is equivalent to what you have (if `client_id` and `buyer_id` columns are not nullable.)

Comment: @ypercube, Basically I have simplified my query a long way to show you just the problem, I have 3 INNER and 4 LEFT JOIN and big WHERE clause in my original query. I will try to put only the mentioned query on fiddle if this is fine with you.

Comment: I don't mind but if the problem is efficiency, then I don't think you'll avoid posting the full query.

Comment: @ypercube, here is the mini version of the problem. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5f9f3/6

Comment: @TalhaAhmedKhan: In your SQLFiddle, both queries return the same number of records.

Comment: but the time taken by `LEFT JOIN` table is more than the `sub-query`. Also the number of record in my DB are different. `LEFT JOIN` gives 500 more records then the original one.

Comment: I ask again. Are there are Nulls in the 3 columns that are used in the joins? (by the way, my query also returns same number of rows: [SQL-Fiddle-3](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5f9f3/11))

Comment: @TalhaAhmedKhan: That may be so, but the point of the SQLFiddle was to replicate the problem in a more manageable form - so far, all you have achieved is to demonstrate the *apparent* validity of this answer. Perhaps if you post the full query (not necessarily with matching data in SQLFiddle) it might be possible to determine the cause?

Answer (score 0):

Your query could be transformed as follows:

```
SELECT
  id, client_id, buyer_id
FROM relation
LEFT JOIN some_table
) AS subquery ON ( subquery.some_id IN (client_id, buyer_id) AND <condition that was in your subquery>)
WHERE subquery.some_id IS NULL;
```

But I have the feeling this will still perform very poorly in terms of execution time.

Consider building a temporary table holding the contents of your subquery.

Answer (score 0):

It would be of help to try putting the fetched values into a separate database table, so that whether there are similar result values or different can now be decided when you already have your results in a separate table. Waiting to hear from your proceedings... Good luck pls.